How to make the background of image transparent in custom tkinter?
I have a button that is an image. I would like to make the background of the image transparent as it is currently showing the png background.
Thank you for any help.
This is my code and what the window currently looks like:
def main_page():
    # Themes
    ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")
    ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")

    # Main Page Window
    app = ctk.CTk()
    app.title("Main Page")
    app.geometry("500x500")
    app.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    app.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    database_image = ctk.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open('database_logo.png'),         
    dark_image=Image.open('database_logo.png'), size=(300, 300))
    database_label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, image=database_image, text="")
    database_button = ctk.CTkButton(app, image= database_image, border_width=0, text="")
    database_button.pack(pady=30)

app.mainloop()



The image dont have .png format, the background is white, you must use a image with correctly format pg. 
